# How to use ngModel from Child Component in the Parent Component?

Tags: angular

My Angular app consist of one large form. I am able to capture the values from each field & post it to a server.

But now, I am trying to re-factor the app into several child components.
I am having the below issue with ngModel when I try to create a child component.

I have created a child component *(selector: app-terms-conditions)*.

Here is the child component code:

**terms-conditions.component.html**

```
<card>
    <card-heading>
        <card-heading-body>
            <h4>Header content</h4>
        </card-heading-body>
    </card-heading>
    <card-body>
        Body content
    </card-body>
    <card-footer>
        <checkbox
          id="accept"
          heading="I accept"
          name="accept"
          value="accept"
          [(ngModel)]="chkAcceptTerms"
          required
          #theChkAcceptTerms="ngModel">
        </checkbox>
      </card-footer>
    </card>
```

Here is where I'm displaying this child component in the parent component:

```
<accordion-body>
    <app-terms-conditions></app-terms-conditions>
</accordion-body>
```

I currently get the following error in **terms-conditions.component.html**:

> Identifier 'chkAcceptTerms' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

This is just one of several child components I have.

I want to capture the selected values from the various child components & post them all together to a server.

Here is an example of some code in the parent component that uses this checkbox before the re-factoring:

```
this.postData(this.chkAcceptTerms, ...);
```

But I don't know if I should pass the values from the child components to the parent, or how to even do that, or is there a better approach?

Can someone please advise me, or perhaps give a concrete example? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go with `Reactive forms` in angular.
First define a form group in service.

```
this.formName = this.formBuilder.group({
  chkAcceptTerms: ['']
})
```

and then share this service across child components:

```
<card-footer [form]="formName">
    <checkbox
      id="accept"
      heading="I accept"
      name="accept"
      value="accept"
      formControlName="chkAcceptTerms"
      required>
    </checkbox>
  </card-footer>
```

More information [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I go with this approach, could I add more child components & just add their formControlName to the service? I.e. have multiple child components in one single form

Comment: yes exactly @user7554035 . you can even add different groups for each child component. This approach is scalable.

Comment: Great, so if I change to using reactive forms. What changes, if any, would I need to make to this method in the parent component: `this.postData(this.chkAcceptTerms, ...);`?

Comment: more information here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-nested-group

Comment: when you want to get all values you just have to do this: `this.postData(this.formName.value)`